# What are some good libraries for extracting data from audio files?

Tags: .net, audio, shazam

Recently I started to use the [Shazam app](http://shazam.com) on my iPhone. For those who don't know, this app identifies songs by listening to a small segment of the song playing. I was amazed by it's accuracy and speed so I decided to do a little digging.

I found a paper written by one of their developers [here](http://www.ee.columbia.edu/~dpwe/papers/Wang03-shazam.pdf). In the paper the developer goes into a good amount of detail describing the fingerprintng algorithm used in Shazam.

As a pet project Id like to make my own song fingerprinting application so I can get some experience with audio programming.

What are some audio libraries that help you extract things like frequency, amplitude, and other characteristics of an audio clip or mp3 song over it's duration?

I'm using .NET but I'm open to other languages libraries. I'm also fine with both open source and paid libraries. As long as I can reliabably extract audio characteristics progmatically I'll be happy.

See also:
[How Shazam Works](http://laplacian.wordpress.com/2009/01/10/how-shazam-works/)
[Shazam Journal Paper](http://shazam.com)

Comment: Fantastic article, thanks for that. I always wondered how Shazam works, and now I know. I do a lot of audio programming in C#, including FFT and other DSP, and I'm interested in helping you with this. You can contact me via the website in my profile.

Answer (score 2):

Try having a look at NAudio. It may not have all the audio analysis that your looking for upfront but it is quite extensible and would be a good place to start if your using .Net languages.

Answer (score 1):

To start with audio features, you should first read [this paper](http://recherche.ircam.fr/anasyn/peeters/ARTICLES/Peeters_2003_cuidadoaudiofeatures.pdf).

Many labs have developed their own libraries to extract audio features. 
You can have a look at yafee, aubio, jaudio ....

Comment: it would be nice to have a comment from the person who down voted this answer

Comment: +1 - It is irritating to see someone downvoting our question/answer without any feedback. How can we improve our Qn/Ans without knowing what is its problem (I didn't downvote you)

Comment: the worst this is MrMage downvoted my answer because I did downvote his ... But at least when I did I explained why I though is answer was not appropriated!

Answer (score -1):

The `ffmpeg` library supports a lot of audio codecs, but it's quite a pain to interface with, IMHO.

For extracting audio properties, you should consider a decent library suited for signal analysis. You will especially need the Fast Fourier Transformation (FTT), for example, to extract frequency data out of your audio samples. [A search](http://www.google.de/search?hl=de&safe=off&num=50&q=signal+analysis+library&btnG=Suche&meta=lr%3Dlang_en|lang_de) gives a lot of results on that topic.

/edit: For .NET, I am confident there is a `ffmpeg` interface. You will find signal analysis tools for .NET, too.

Comment: What he is looking for is a toolbox to extract what is called "audio features" or "audio descriptor" . The design of audio descriptor is part of a research field named "music information retrieval" .